# How do I get an event that a mail was sent through SmtpClient C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, smtpclient

I am trying to build a system for sending newsletters from my website.

I am building it as a console app which I will then execute daily from windows scheduler.

I want to have some logging in the system, so I am adding the most simple log "feature".

The mails are sent fine, but I would like to write in the log when a mail is sent. The problem is that I don't know how to get an event from the SmtpClient when the mail was sent or the mail was not sent.

```
public void SendMails(List<Agent> agents, string logfilename)
{
    foreach (Agent agent in agents)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.....

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.....

        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
            WriteLog(logfilename, "Sent mail to: " + mail.To[0].Address);
        }
        catch (SmtpException smtpexception)
        {
            WriteLog(logfilename, "SMTP EXCEPTION: " + smtpexception.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteLog(logfilename, "EXCEPTION: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}

public void WriteLog(string filename, string message)
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\MailLogs\" + filename + ".txt");
    tw.WriteLine(message);
    tw.Close();
}
```

So, how do I change the code, so I can write the log after the program actually knows whether the mail was sent or not...

Answer (score 1):

if you execute the line `client.Send(mail);` which is not async and it does not throw an Exception it means that the mail has been sent.

Whether it is delivered or not you will not be able to see as that is handled by your smtp server and as far as I know the SmtpClient does not support an event for that.

Comment: Yeah, but the mails will be queued on the smtp server and the program ends before any exception might be thrown as the exceptions are being delayed. I tried testing with a couple of addresses and all the mails were sent, but not all the log lines were written.

Comment: I can't see how all the log lines were not written, reason being that the only way that the "Sent mail to:" log line will not execute is if an exception is thrown and then the mail should not be sent. Are you using multiple threads perhaps and the error is happening in the WriteLog method? Try writing it to the console/debug instead of to a file and see if that outputs all the mails.

Comment: If I add Console.ReadLine() in the end of the main method and just lets it sit there and wait. All lines are written. If not, it seems like some of the last logs are not written, even though the mails are sent... That's the thing.

Comment: The only reason for that I can think of would be if you are using threading with the WriteLog? otherwise your log files are still written with the main thread which will only exit once all the code is executed. Looking at your code though, you are not using threading so this is very strange

Answer (score 0):

SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();

sc.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendAsyncCallback);

Answer (score 0):

Your code is itself doing so now. If `WriteLog()` does write `Sent Email to...`, it means mail has been sent else not.